# How to make my swagger curl match my apache config?

Tags: python-3.x, apache, flask, gunicorn, flask-restx

I'm running flask restx behind gunicorn and apache. My team only gets one server for all our tools so it's kind of necessary.

But in order to work w/ port 443 and https, I'm having to proxy my requests through apache and gunicorn.
Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName webdev02.mycompany.com

  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/etc/httpd/htdocs"

  <Directory "/etc/httpd/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ## Logging
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/httpd_error_log"
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/httpd_access_log" "mainserver"

  ## Server aliases
  ServerAlias webdev02.mycompany.com

  ## Custom fragment
  ## Custom fragment
  SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/httpd_access_log" combined env=!forwarded
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/httpd_access_log" proxy env=forwarded
<Location "literally 11 other applications">
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:80##/
</Location>
<Location /my_application>
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8082/
</Location>
<Location /swaggerui> # this has to be done to find the swaggerui page
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8082/swaggerui
</Location>
<Location /swagger.json> # because my_application represents the project running on port 8082, I have to redirect here to retrieve the swagger.json file
  ProxyPass http://webdev02.mycompany.com/my_application/swagger.json
</Location>
<Location /hosts/> # this is the start of my problems
  ProxyPass http://webdev02.mycompany.com/my_application/hosts/
</Location>
  SetEnv HTTPS On

</VirtualHost>
```

Flask code:

```
#main.py
from flask import Flask
from api_model import api
from api_view import namespace
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_proto=1, x_port=1, x_for=1, x_host=1, x_prefix=1)
api.init_app(app)
api.add_namespace(namespace)

#api_view.py
from flask import request
from flask_restx import Namespace, Resource
from api_controller import ApiController
from api_model import host_get_model, host_put_model_send, host_put_model_return, host_fail_model
controller = ApiController()

namespace = Namespace('hosts', 'host endpoints')


@namespace.route('/<vmname>')
class Host(Resource):
    """Read, update and delete a specific host"""

    # @namespace.response(204, 'host not found')
    @namespace.response(500, 'Internal Server error')
    @namespace.marshal_with(host_get_model, mask='')
    def get(self, vmname):
        """Get host information"""
        arguments = {"vmname": vmname}
        result, status_code = controller.get_host_from_db(arguments)
        return result, status_code


@namespace.route('/')
class Host(Resource):
    @namespace.expect(host_put_model_send, validate=True)
    @namespace.marshal_with(host_put_model_return, mask='')
    def put(self):
        """Update host information"""
        data = request.json
        arguments = {"vmname": data["vmname"], "patchwindow": data["PatchWindow"]}
        result, status_code = controller.update_host_from_db(arguments)
        return result, status_code
    
#api_model.py
from flask_restx import fields, Api
api = Api(title="My_API", description="testing", doc="/")

host_get_model = api.model('host_get', {
    'vmname': fields.String(
        required=True,
        example='localhost',
        description='Fully Qualified Domain Name of server'
    ),
    'OS': fields.String(
        readonly=True,
        example='Linux',
        description='OS Type. Currently just Linux is available'
    ),
    'PatchWindow': fields.String(
        readonly=True,
        example='Mon_1800',
        description='Current PatchWindow'
    )
})
```

A curl requests works like so:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://webdev02.mycompany.com/my_application/hosts/myserver.mycompany.com' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
{"vmname": "myserver.mycompany.com", "OS": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8", "PatchWindow": "1_Mon_AM_6"}
```

the problem: my swagger page does not recognize that it is behind Apache and Gunicorn. When I go to my swagger doc page, select that same endpoint above and hit execute, it outputs the CURL like this:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://webdev02.mycompany.com/hosts/myserver.mycompany.com' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

What do I need to do to get my swagger example to match the actual location I'm creating w/ Apache?